# How to compare pointer to strings in C

Tags: c

how to compare two strings in C? Help me, I am beginner@@

```
char *str1 = "hello";
char *str2 = "world";
//compare str1 and str2 ?
```

Comment: Those should be `const char *`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may want to use [`strcmp`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/strcmp.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int v;
    const char *str1 = "hello";
    const char *str2 = "world";

    v = strcmp(str1, str2);

    if (v < 0)
        printf("'%s' is less than '%s'.\n", str1, str2);
    else if (v == 0)
        printf("'%s' equals '%s'.\n", str1, str2);
    else if (v > 0)
        printf("'%s' is greater than '%s'.\n", str1, str2);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
'hello' is less than 'world'.
```

Comment: +1, but I wouldn't link to that page, it uses the horrible outdated `gets` function in its example, which is definitely not a good idea for someone beginning C. The [POSIX page](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/strcmp.html) is an alternative.

Answer (score 5):

```
if ( strcmp( str1, str2 ) == 0 )
  same
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare two `char*`s using the `strcmp` [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731.aspx).