# Comparing buffer with a C String

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compare pointer to strings in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663668/how-to-compare-pointer-to-strings-in-c)

How to compare the characters in a buffer with a string?

Comment: Can you explain your problem clearly?

Comment: If possible, give an example.

Comment: i tried comparing the contents of a buffer with a string. like strcmp(buffer,"change")

Answer (score 2):

By buffer, I assume its not NULL terminated. Then you can not use `strcmp`, instead you can use [strncmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncmp/).

Comment: it is specifying as too few arguments: strncmp(buffer,"change")

Comment: @neha: It takes 3 arguments (see link). Third argument is the number of characters in the buffer. Note that it matches *substring*. If you want the exact match then you need to compare the string length with number of characters in the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, the buffer is an array of characters. You can compare character by character. Example -

```
char buffer[] = { 'a','b','c' };
char* str = "b";

int i=0;
while( i<3 )
{
    if( buffer[i] == *str )
        printf("\n Equal \n" );
    else
        printf("\n Not Equal \n" );

    ++i;
}
```

The above code should give you basic idea of how to implement. Results : [IdeOne](http://ideone.com/YTSfW)

Things you need to think of to answer the question -

- What if the value pointed by `str` is `"abc"`?
- What if the entire buffer needs to be compared to value pointed by `char*` ( i.e., buffer is equal to value pointed by `char*` ?

Answer (score 1):

Something that throws a lot of people off at first is that `strcmp` returns **0** if the strings match, so you usually use something like `if (!strcmp(buffer, "change"))`

Answer (score 0):

```
int strcmp ( const char *s1, const char *s2 );
```

Try this. It will help you.

Comment: i tried strcmp(buffer, "change").