# C++ MFC how to compare LPCTSTR in a if statement?

Tags: c++, string, mfc, compare, lpcstr

I have the following code:

```
LPCTSTR strPermission = Method();

if (strPermission == L"0")
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

While debugging I can see that strPermission does equal "0", yet when I compare it like in the if statement it always returns false.

The only thing I can think of is that it is comparing the memory address of the variable rather than the variable value.

How do I compare strPermission to L"0" so that it would return true if strPermission equals "0".

Thank you!

Comment: LPCTSTR is either `const char*` or `const wchar_t*`, so think about it. Also, shouldn't you be checking for NULL or the null terminator and not the string literal "0"?

Comment: You can use C-style string-comparison functions, but use the version for TCHAR, which is [tcscmp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: Oops, I meant `_tcscmp`, if you tried the first one to some disappointment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare pointer to strings in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663668/how-to-compare-pointer-to-strings-in-c)

Comment: Close, but these data types are a bit more specific. That is the main issue here though.

Comment: May one ask what the circumstances are that force you to support Windows 9x (by using the T stuff)?

Comment: For me I create a CString variable and use `.Compare()` to compare `LPCTSTR`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use a C runtime library function. `strcmp` compares ANSI strings, `wcscmp` compares UNICODE strings.

You use it like this:

```
bool match = wcscmp(strPermission, L"0") == 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare C-style strings like that in C or C++. Check out this [C FAQ question & answer](http://c-faq.com/charstring/stringeq.html).

The function you're looking for is called [`lstrcmp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647488%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`LPCTSTR` is a pointer to an array of `const wchar_t`.  `strPermission` points to the first character of the array.  `L"0"` is a string literal, which is an array of `const wchar_t`, which decays to a pointer of `const wchar_t`.  But the pointers are not equal, they point to different arrays.  This is *why* we invented C++.  Please use it.

```
std::wstring strPermission = Method();
return (strPermission == L"0"); //works like magic!
```

or, if `Method` is returning something you have to retain, at *least* do this

```
std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]> strPermission = Method();
return (std::wcscmp(strPermission.get(), L"0")==0); 
//wcscmp is for comparing strings, but returns 0 if they're equal.
```

Also, are you sure that `strPemission` points to an array that contains a zero character followed by a null character?  If not, and you're not using `wstring`, then you also have to check that it points at an array

```
if (strPermission)
     //do stuff
else
     //its a NULL pointer.
```

I have been prodded by chris to point out that the type of `LPCTSTR` actually depends on the compiler options.  I can tell by your code that you're coding with `_UNICODE` set, which makes it a `const wchar_t*`, but if you want to be able to compile with other options (I can't think of a good reason to do so) you should use `_tcscmp` to compare, have the literals as `_T("0")` and they'll be arrays of `TCAHR`.  For the strings, you'll have to add a typedef somewhere:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
    typedef std::string std::tstring 
    //you'll probably have to add more t helper functions here
#else
    typedef std::string std::wstring
    //you'll probably have to add more t helper functions here
#endif
```

If you want to be certain that your code is *always* `_UNICODE` (which is what I do), explicitly call `MethodW()` instead of `Method()`.  (There is also a corresponding `MethodA()`, but not much reason to call it).

There's also a `UNICODE` macro, but it should always be the same as the `_UNICODE` macro.  (Never define these yourself, they belong in the project options)

Comment: The thing is that although you can assume LPCTSTR is a LPCWSTR because of the L"0" in the question, it is technically a `const TCHAR *`.

Comment: @chris: technically it is, but I ignored that.  I'll add a comment.