# Why doesn't t != "Q" kill while loop when gets(t) gets input "Q" from command line?

Tags: c, character, string-comparison, gets

I'm declaring `t[1] = "a"` and have `gets(t)` in while loop, checking for condition `t != "Q"` every time it loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char t[1] = "a";
    printf("Enter a character or 'Q' to quit.");

    while (t != "Q")
    {
        gets(t);
        printf("%s\n", t);
    }
return(0);
}
```

The program just keeps looping even when I input Q and press enter.

Comment: Because you are comparing the addresses of the first characters rather than the strings.  Use `strcmp` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare pointer to strings in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663668/how-to-compare-pointer-to-strings-in-c)

Comment: Also, you're performing a case-sensitive comparison. I imagine most input would actually be `q`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your program.

```
char t[1] = "a";
```

A *string* consists of a sequence of characters terminated by a null character `'\0'`. You haven't left enough room in `t` to hold the character `'a'` plus the terminating `'\0'`. Due to a special rule, this stores just the character `'a'` in `t[0]`; this `t` doesn't contain a string.

```
while (t != "Q")
```

Here's the most direct cause of the problem you're seeing.  C doesn't support equality comparisons for strings, or for arrays.  An array expression usually "decays" to a pointer to its first element.  This compares the address of the first element of `t` to the address of the first element of the string literal `"Q"`.  Obviously they'll never be equal.

```
gets(t);
```

Never use the `gets` function. It is inherently unsafe; it doesn't let you specify how long the target array is, so you can't avoid writing past the end of the array. Since `t` is only one element long, this *will* overflow (unless you type an empty line).

For what you're doing, you probably want to read a single character at a time, probably using `getchar()`. Remember that `getchar()` returns an `int`, not `char`; it returns `EOF` to indicate end-of-file. And if you type, for example, `Q` followed by Enter, two calls to `getchar()` will return `'Q'` and `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

`t` stands for address of your array. So you are comparing address to string. Use t[0] != 'Q' or strcmp(t, "Q") != 0.

Comment: Thanks. I compared t[0] to 'Q' to get the element and that worked. unfortunately I don't have enough 'reputation' to up-vote your answer.

Comment: strcmp will not do it, because 't' is only one char and has no trailing terminator character.

Comment: @user3629249 Good point. So use t[0] != 'Q' or change `char t[1] = "a";` to `char t[2] = "a";` and use strcmp.