# The following code for palindrome doesn't work?is there a logical mistake?

Tags: c, logic, palindrome

Could someone point me to the error in this code. Iam using codingblocks IDE.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    char a[100],b[100];int i,j=0; 
    scanf("%s",&a);
    for(i=strlen(a)-1,j=0;i>=0;i--)
    {
        b[j]=a[i];
        j=j+1;
    }
    b[j]='\0';
    if(a==b) # on printing i get both 'a' and 'b' as equal however this condition still remains
             # false

        printf("true"); #doesnot print?

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare pointer to strings in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663668/how-to-compare-pointer-to-strings-in-c)

Comment: `#` isn't a comment character in `C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this statement

```
if(a==b)
```

to

```
if ( strcmp( a, b ) == 0 )
```

Otherwise you are comparing addresses of the first elements of the arrays.

Also you need to include header `<string.h>`. Function main shall have return type `int`. Change this statement

```
scanf("%s",&a);
```

to

```
scanf( "%s", a);
```

Take into account that there is no need to define second array that to determine whether a string is a palindrome. You could do this check "in place".

Answer (score 1):

Few issues in your code

- You never copy anything in `b`, so that array has random characters.
- `a==b` will always be false because they are character arrays not pointers and both contain different values.
- If you are reading string, you don't need `&` for char array, so the `scanf()` should be `scanf("%s",a);`