# C user input to array used as if statement

Tags: c, string-comparison, command-line-arguments

I am writing code that is taken from the command line. The user will input lets say for example `./a.out -l 2 4 6` into the command line. The goal here is to loop through the array and see if either `'-l'` or `'-s'` appear. If '`-l'` appears it makes x = 1 , if `'-s'` x = 2 if neither x = 0. Right now the issue being thrown is comparison between pointer and integer on line 7 and 12. Also a multi-character character constant on line 12, which I'm not sure why its being thrown when line 9 is okay. How would I change my `if` statements to fix the issues being thrown? My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  int x;

  for(; *argv != '\0'; argv++){
    if(*argv == '-l'){
      x = 1;
  }
    else if(*argv == '-s'){
      x = 2; 
  } 
    else{
     x = 0;
  }
}
  printf("%d",x);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare pointer to strings in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663668/how-to-compare-pointer-to-strings-in-c)

Comment: Same answer slightly different question, I am not comparing two strings but looking for a char from a string input that is now in an array

Comment: Yes you are trying to compare two strings... If not, why did you write `*argv == '-s'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are specified with double quotes, not single quotes which are used for characters.  Also, you can't use `==` to compare strings.  Use `strcmp` for that:

```
if(strcmp(*argv,"-l") == 0){

...

if(strcmp(*argv,"-s") == 0){
```

Your output will also not be as you expect.  You overwrite `x` each time you check the next parameter, so the result will depend only on the last one.  You need to `break` out of the loop when one of the two conditions is met.

Comment: my output is x = 0 which is not the correct when I do `./a.out -l 2 4 6` any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the errors pointed out by others, you might at some point want to do proper command line parsing.  On a POSIX system , this is done with the `getopt()` library function declared in the `unistd.h` header (this is *not* "C standard" C code).

I've extended your requirements with an option `-x` that takes an integer argument that says what `x` should be set to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int x = 0; /* default zero for x */
    int i, tmp;
    int opt;

    char *endptr;

    /* the ':' in the string means "the previous letter takes an argument" */
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "lsx:")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
        case 'l':
            x = 1;
            break;
        case 's':
            x = 2;
            break;
        case 'x':
            /* validate input, must be integer */
            tmp = (int)strtol(optarg, &endptr, 10);
            if (*optarg == '\0' || *endptr != '\0')
                printf("Illegal value for x: '%s'\n", optarg);
            else
                x = tmp;
            break;
        case '?': /* fallthrough */
        default:
            /* call routine that outputs usage info here */
            puts("Expected -s, -l or -x N");
        }
    }

    argc -= optind; /* adjust */
    argv += optind; /* adjust */

    printf("x = %d\n", x);

    puts("Other things on the command line:");
    for (i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        printf("\t%s\n", argv[i]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Running it:

```
$ ./a.out -l
x = 1
Other things on the command line:

$ ./a.out -s
x = 2
Other things on the command line:
```

The last option "wins":

```
$ ./a.out -s -x -78
x = -78
Other things on the command line:
```

Here, `-s` is last:

```
$ ./a.out -s -x -78 -ls
x = 2
Other things on the command line:

$ ./a.out -s -q
./a.out: illegal option -- q
Expected -s, -l or -x N
x = 2
Other things on the command line:
```

Parsing stops at the first non-option:

```
$ ./a.out -s "hello world" 8 9 -x 90
x = 2
Other things on the command line:
    hello world
    8
    9
    -x
    90
```