# Pointers with If statements in C

Tags: c, pointers, if-statement

I am writing a text-based game in C. At the start of the program, it prompts you if you want to start or end the game. However, when I type end or start, it brings up a "Segmentation Fault" error. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

//Variables
char *name, *answer ;

//Beginning of program
int main()
{
//Game starts and prompts you
printf ("--|| YOUR_ADVENTURE_HERE ||-- \n") ;
printf (" \n") ;
printf ("Type 'START' to start the game or 'END' to end the game. You can end the game at any point by typing it as well.") ;
scanf ("%59s, answer") ;

//If typed 'START'
if (answer = "START")
{
printf ("\n") ;
printf ("Starting game...") ;
sleep (5) ;

return 0 ;
}

//If they typed 'END' (this will be used in every scanf)
if (answer = "END")
{
system("exit") ;

return 0 ;  
}
```

Here is also how it looks when I run it:

```
--|| YOUR_ADVENTURE_HERE ||-- 

Type 'START' to start the game or 'END' to end the game. You can end the game at any point by typing it as well.START
Segmentation fault
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `==` for comparison, `=` for assignment

Comment: A single = sign is always assignment, if you want to compare then you'll need to use == or strcmp (you should prefer strcmp) as seen here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663668/how-to-compare-pointer-to-strings-in-c

Comment: Your compiler should warn. Treat them like errors. If it does not, enable all recommended warnings.

Comment: @Olaf On `gcc` or `clang`, by the way, someone can turn on all recommended warnings with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`.  (Yes, all doesn’t mean all.)  You might also throw in `-std=c11` to get it to warn about non-portable code.

Comment: Also, prefer `strncmp()` to `strcmp()`, `strncpy()` to `strcpy()`, and so on.  Always bounds-check your buffer reads and writes in C.  You’ll save yourself a lot of segfaults and (should they become relevant) security holes.

Comment: Line 15, your quotes are off.

Comment: @Davislor: Thanks, I left that intentionally open. Those are listed/linked on the info page, btw. And they are **not** all recommended options, `-Wconversion`, for example is not included in any of the above. `-Wpedantic` is problematic if you use extensions. It also does **not** warn about all issues (see the documentation), at least for gcc.

Comment: @Olaf They’re the warnings *I* recommended. ;)

Comment: @Davislor: Well, you should point that out! And recosider, they are not sufficient for beginners.

Comment: @olaf Okay, what do you recommend for a beginner using clang? I had been writing C and C++ for years before I used either gcc or clang.

Comment: @Olaf Maybe that should be a Software Engineering question.

Comment: @Davislor: As every new version of gcc and clang support different warnings (mostly more, but sometimes also changed sets), walk through the documentation and pick all which sound not unreasonable. If you experience too many unwarranted warnings, remove/disable the corresponding warning. gcc at least shows which option triggered a message.

Comment: @Olaf Like the warning that I’m using C++14 extensions even when I tell it `-std=c++14`? By the way, the list for clang 5: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html

Comment: @Davislor when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Sorry, sorry. I meant, maybe I should post *my* question about what compiler warnings a beginner should turn on over at SE. (Unless it’s a duplicate.) The question is a tangent on this thread and off-topic on SO because it’s a matter of opinion about best practice.

Comment: @Davislor your question also seems poor fit, see [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: @gnat Maybe. It can be decomposed into a list of yes-or-no questions for each `-W` option the compiler in question supports, of the form “Should I/a beginner compile with *-Wfoo* on *bar++x.y.z*?” Each one in principle has one answer, with arguments in favor of that answer being yes or it being no. And a lot of good problem statements lead to more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: @Davislor this way looks slippery, see [Question closed because yes/no answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183183/165773)

Comment: @gnat Okay, I’ll take your advice and not post it. Someone else who disagrees would be free to.

Answer (score 9):

Allocate memory to pointer before trying to store anything there.

`scanf ("%59s, answer") ;`

should be preceded by a memory allocation for `answer`

```
answer = malloc(60);
scanf ("%59s", answer) ;
```

**Also**, on a side note, use `strcmp` to compare strings.

`if (answer = "START")`

should be

`if (!strcmp(answer,"START"))`

Comment: You have overlooked the parameter error to `scanf`.

Comment: @wallyk. aah, I missed it. Just edited my answer to include it.

Comment: Do you not like `scanf ("%m[^\n]%*c", &answer);`? (`%a` for older versions)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is here:

```
scanf ("%59s, answer");
```

First, scanf requires a list of arguments to write values obtained from input.  You haven't provided any.  Instead, you have only one long string.  Surely what you meant was:

```
scanf ("%59s", answer);
```

But even that won't work.

It requires that `answer` be allocated memory of some kind, and *not* be an uninitialized pointer.  This will work better:

```
char answer [60];
scanf ("%59s", answer);
```

I didn't look any further for other problems.