# Command-Line Arguments Problem in C-language in Kali Linux?

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to develop a program that will display contents of a file and copies content of file1.txt to file2.txt in kali linux using command-line arguments.
Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){`

    char show[6] = "--show";
    char copy[6] = "--copy";
    char help[2] ="-h";

    if(argc == 3){
        // chandu --show filename
        if(strcmp(argv[1],show)){ // strcmp => compares two strings.
            FILE *sfile;
            char ch;
            sfile=fopen(argv[2],"r");
            while((ch = fgetc(sfile)) != EOF){
                if(ferror(sfile)){
                    perror("I/W");
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    printf("%c",ch);
                }
            }
            fclose(sfile);
            exit(0);
        }else{
            puts("use -h for help.\n");
        }
    }
```

Problem is : Displaying content must work with `./chandu --show meow.txt` but it works with `./chandu show meow.txt` .Means with double hyphen (--) it does'nt work and without hyphen, it works. Why ? I can't figure it out. Please help.

I changed `strcmp()` to `strncmp()` so that it could run (hit-trial method) but it didn't.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your arrays are too small to hold strings: `char show[6] = "--show";` This array cannot hold the terminating 0 byte. That means it is not a string and passing it to `strcmp` causes undefined behaviour. Same for the 2 other arrays. Increase them by 1 element or remove the size completely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare pointer to strings in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663668/how-to-compare-pointer-to-strings-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcmp` returns 0 is the two strings are equal, and `0` means the `if`'s condition **won't** be executed. You could explicitly compare the result to `0`:

```c
if(strcmp(argv[1], show) == 0) {
  // Here ---------------^
```

Comment: thanks.. I just figured it out and was writing answer but now it's no need to write answer.